# Evaluation of symbolic Differentiation with Sympy in Python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm coding NewtonRaphson algorithm in python using Sympy library, this is my algorithm implementation:

```
def NewtonRaphson(fx,p0,tolerancia,iteracionesMaximas):
    print
    fx = S(fx)
    x = Symbol('x')
    i = 1
    p = 0.0

    while i<= iteracionesMaximas:
        
        y = fx.subs(x,p0)
        yy = diff(fx,x).subs(x,p0)
        p = p0 - (y/yy)

        if absolute(p-p0) < tolerancia:
            print "Se encontró la raíz y={raiz} luego de {n} iteraciones".format(raiz=p, n=i-1)
            return

        i += 1
        print "{i}\t{p}\t{p0}".format(i=i-1,p=p,p0=p0)
        p = p0

    print "El método falló luego de {i} iteraciones".format(i=i-1)
```

I'm obtaining a raise with the following message:

```
line 18, in NewtonRaphson    
    yy = diff(fx,x).subs(x,p0)    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 984, in diff    
    if n < 0:    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 226, in __nonzero__    
    raise TypeError("symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.")    
TypeError: symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.
```

I call function being `fx` a string equal to `'x**3-x-1'`and input the call `NewtonRaphson(fx,1.7,10**(-4),17)`.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Show the whole traceback.

Comment: What's the value of `fx`?

Comment: I call x as `'x**3-x-1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a symbolic expression to numpy's absolute function.
Judging by your code I'd bet that your import statements were

```
from pylab import *
from sympy import *
```

If that was the case, you should just replace `absolute` with `Abs` so that you are using the absolute value function built in to sympy instead of the one meant for numpy arrays.

Also, you will need to replace `p = p0` with `p0 = p` for the algorithm to run properly.

Here is a working version with the import statements changed somewhat.
I have also removed some of the unnecessary statements.

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.symbols('x')
fx = x**3 - x - 1

def NewtonRaphson(fx,p0,tolerancia,iteracionesMaximas):

    for i in xrange(iteracionesMaximas):

        y = fx.subs(x, p0)
        yy = sy.diff(fx,x).subs(x, p0)
        p = p0 - (y / yy)

        if sy.Abs(p-p0) < tolerancia:
            print "Se encontró la raíz y={raiz} luego de {n} iteraciones".format(raiz=p, n=i-1)
            return

        print "{i}\t{p}\t{p0}".format(i=i+1,p=p,p0=p0)
        p0 = p

    print "El método falló luego de {i} iteraciones".format(i=i-1)

NewtonRaphson(fx,1.7,10**(-4),17)
```